# Creating site with hindi fonts with I18n feature of Struts2

Tags: internationalization, struts2

Hi I am trying to create an application with hindi fonts (Only Lable required to be shown in hindi)with the help of Struts2 i18n feature. 
I have cretaed required properties file as global_hi.properties 
for the label username ,password and submit button. 
It works fine for submit button,but for password its showing *??? . 
I have attached my jsp ,struts.xml and proerties fiel. 
struts.xml is

```
 <struts>
        <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <package name="default" extends="struts-default, tiles-default,jfreechart-default">
            <interceptors>
                <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" class="common.AuthenticationInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-stack name="chkSession">
                    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
                    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
                    <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor" />
                </interceptor-stack>
            </interceptors>

            <global-results>
                <result name="invalid.token">common/doublePost.jsp</result>
                <result name="loginAction" type="redirect">/sessionnotfound.jsp</result>

            </global-results>


            <action name="showHomePage">
                <result type="tiles">Login</result>
            </action>
            <action name="locale">
                <result type="tiles">Login</result>
            </action>
        </package>
</struts>
```

my jsp is

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

        <head>
            <title>Administration Login</title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
            <link href="/LiquorShopManagementSystem/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

            <s:head/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header"></div>
            <s:form name="frmAdminLogin" id="frmAdminLogin" method="post" action="doLogin" validate="true">
                <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-right:fuchsia 2px solid;">
                            <img src="/LiquorShopManagementSystem/images/BookShop.jpg" height="250"/>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" width="248px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="spanHeader">
                                        <span>Back Officeghj</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" align="left" class="error">
                                        <s:property value="message" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="middle">
                                         <s:textfield required="true" requiredposition="left" maxLength="25" key="global.username" name="userMaster.loginid" title="Enter Username"/>
                                         <s:password required="true" requiredposition="left" maxLength="8" key="global.password" name="userMaster.Password" title="Enter Password"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <s:submit cssClass="buttonText" cssStyle="background:url(/BookShop/images/submit_bg.gif) no-repeat scroll 37px 0px;" name="login" key="global.submit" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and properties file is

```
#Global messages
global.username = Username
global.password =\u0938\u092E\u094D\u092E\u0947\u0932\u0928
global.submit =\u0938\u092E\u094D\u092E\u0947\u0932\u0928
```

although it is working fine for submit tag.
Can any one suggest for any workaround for this.

thanks

Comment: and how you converted this Hindi text for paswrd field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i tried and its working fine for me.All i changed the value in my property file

```
global.password=\u092A\u093E\u0938\u0935\u0930\u094D\u0921
```

and here is the output screenshot

[image]

i believe you need to check the way you are encoding your Hindi characters.
surprising, it giving following output when i am using your entries..

[image]